# Firebase UID and setting custom Admin Rules and Privileges

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database

My current Firebase project rules are set as following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

However, do not really think this is safe to change the `false` values to `true`, and continue using the default functions over such rules. So, I have decided to change the both read and write rules to be only accessed by me and only me. After searching Stack Overflow about that I have found the rules as following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "events": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth.uid === 'dJrGShfgfd2'"
    }
  }
}
```

whereas, by only specifying the UID of the user (in this case it is me), it will be automatically only accessed by that user, however, my question is that how do we get our UID on Firebase?

Comment: You only have a UID if you sign in with Firebase Authentication. Are you doing that? If not, can you point to what library/SDK you use to access your Firebase database?

Comment: Dear Frank, Yes. I am currently signing-in through the Firebase. You can find how my code looks like here

[link](https://woosal.com/1337/woosal1337-Uo9SZ8yynrvxEMl25zQ8BbNzANVgiAz7OkQ0TzvMbEf8y5SVoP531PYcN3FvoF5UlvcEF2UmQljBlHTtTDanu2Xvu.png)

Comment: I want to know what library or SDK you use, typically a link to where you get it from would be best. Please provide this information in your question, and as text (no screenshots of text are needed). That also gives you a chance to show how you are currently signing in to Firebase.

Comment: I am currently using the official Python SDK, which I got from the Firebase Docs.

Comment: To be more precise, I am looking for something like this
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YqQs.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Python SDK is an Admin SDK, which means that:

1. It provides administrative access to your Firebase project.
2. You can't sign in to Firebase with the Admin SDK, but instead provide service account credentials to initialize it.
3. It doesn't adhere to the security rules of your database, unless you explicitly [authenticate with limited privileges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges). In that you can specify any UID you want in the `databaseAuthVariableOverride`, as no check on its existence is done.

Comment: So, what I understood at first, was actually every Firebase users get a Firebase unique UID, which can be usedd as to invite anyone on Firebase to your project and give custom permissions on the read/write rules. With that being said, I though if I could also access that GUI where I can also find mine, I would be easily just add it to my rules as write access, and leave the rest the same. So, is this a wrong approach?

Comment: The Admin SDKs do not access the project as a Firebase Authentication user, but as an administrative/service account. That's why their access is not controlled by security rules. #3 is a workaround, that allows the Admin SDK to impersonate *any* Firebase Auth user.

Comment: Alrighty, Frank. Thank you so much for the answer and your time, appreciated. Have a good day ahead!